# Difference in reading newlines using std::ifstream and getc

Tags: c++

If I read in a file using this:

```
std::string readfile(const std::string &filename)
{
    std::ifstream t(filename);
    std::string str;
    str.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t),
               std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    return str;
}
```

I find that the returned string has newlines which differ from the file's actual content. The file uses `\r\n`, whereas the returned string only contains `\n`.

I confirmed this by using an old c-style function:

```
std::string readfile_c(const std::string &filename)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");
    std::string str;
    char c;
    while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF)
        str.push_back(c);
    fclose(f);
    return str;
}
```

Trying them both out:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const std::string filename = "work\\actionlabel.html";
    std::string content1(readfile(filename));
    std::string content2(readfile_c(filename));
}
```

gives me this:

[image: debugger]

As shown, `content1` (from *readfile*) has only **\n** newlines, and `content2` (from *readfile_c*) has the file's actual newlines **\r\n**.

Why is there a difference?

Comment: Please don't tag C++ questions as C.

Comment: @tadman My question asks about a comparison between C++ functions and C functions. So both tags seem relevant to me.

Comment: Add `std::ios::binary` to the [constructor of `std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream).

Comment: @O'Neil Well that was easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams default to *text mode* in which the content of the file may not match the content seen by the stream. For example in Windows, a disk file contains `\r\n` line endings but the C++ text stream will only see `\n` for the line endings. This feature helps in writing portable code that has to deal with differing OS conventions.

In *binary mode* it is intended that the file content, exactly matches the content seen by the stream.

In the code `fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");` you specified binary mode, but in your `ifstream` you did not; giving you text mode.

To get the same behaviour in both cases you could either use `"r"` for `fopen`, giving text mode in both cases, or use `std::ios::binary` as second argument to `ifstream`, giving binary mode in both cases.